# Почему объектные файлы не кроссплатформенны?

Tags: c, gcc, компиляция, компилятор

По [определению](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C), объектный код - набор инструкций для определённой архитектуры процессора.
Возьмём компилятор GCC. Если компилировать один и тот же код из-под разных платформ(Linux/Windows etc.), но на одном железе, на выходе получим с виду одинаковые *.o файлы, которые не будут кросплатформенны. Почему?

Чтобы исключить разность реализаций библиотек, возьмём код без них, что-то вроде:

```
//main.c
int main()
{
    return 5+3;
}
//main.c EOF
```

Comment: Погуляйте по объектникам с помощью `objdump`. Увидите, что у каждой платформы свои тараканы, необходимые для окончательной сборки исполняемого файла.

Comment: Вы забываете про инициализацию перед стартом main...

Comment: У каждой платформы свои системные вызовы, свои соглашения о передаче параметров, своя реализация стандартной библиотеки. А ещё у C++ **нету бинарного стандарта**. Вот если кто-нибудь уговорит разработчиков систем это всё унифицировать, и комитет по стандартизации принять бинарный стандарт, согласившись с возможной однопроцентной потерей эффективности (которая в мире плюсов считается священной коровой), тогда и можно будет говорить о кросс-платформенности объектных файлов.

Comment: @VladD, значит, всё-таки, объектные файлы - не набор инструкций процессора и его микропрограмм, а код для платформы под которой его скомпилировали?

Comment: @DimTeam: А в чём отличие? Код ведь не бежит в вакууме на чистом процессоре. Он вызывает другие функции, может быть неявно. У него есть конвенции передачи параметров. Всё сложно :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> По определению, объектный код - набор инструкций для определённой
>   архитектуры процессора.

Это правда. Но НЕ вся правда. Кроме собственно инструкций процессора он содержит таблицу внешних ссылок, таблицу перемещаемых адресов и т.д. Эти таблицы используются загрузчиком/линкером при подготовки объектного модуля к выполнению.

Ни сами таблицы, ни метод настройки объектного модуля не стандартизованы. В силу этого, объектный модуль, подготовленный для исполнения на одной платформе, не может быть выполнен на другой.

Можно было бы попытаться написать не очень сложный транслятор одного формата в другой, но проблема практически неразрешима, т.к. различается не только сам формат объектного модуля, но и формат вызовов внешних функций (структура стека) и даже формат вызова функций ОС. Дело дохлое...